# How to find out a model function for two inputs?

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, data-modeling, modeling

I am doing a bit of machine learning for a control for an end user for a system. I am basically trying to figure out a delay number based on two inputs.
Currently I collect a list of times (in milliseconds) of how long it takes for the user to interact with the control. I figure based on these two things, I can get a delay number.

1) length of the list

2) the times in the list

(I record a value in the list each time the user hovers on the control. Also it's possible they might go on the system but not hover on the control)

The delay number is just a number that says wait this long before actually downloading the content for the control. Because if the user doesn't interact with the control, then I want a longer delay factor, this way it puts less load on the server.

The problem I am stuck on is how to use the two values I collected above to determine the delay time.

I was thinking of 4 scenarios:

1) if long list and average time is big, then put a medium delay time

2) if long list and average time is small, then put a short delay time

3) if short list and average time is big, then put a long delay time

4) if short list and average time is small, then put a medium delay time

If the list is empty, then perhaps use a medium delay factor.

And then of course a bias factor (which is really a 3rd input) for the delay time because different controls have different priorities.

The above 4 scenarios determine the 4 extremes, and then of course what's inside is a gradient. I kinda need an equation of a function (2 inputs (and bias?) and 1 output, possibly something like `b * f(x,y)` where `x`, `y`, and `f(x,y)` is in `[0,1]`) that models this information.

Does anyone know how I can convert the above inputs into a function and get a delay time from?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a regression problem. You can use one of the many regression models in any machine learning library. I personally use [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html).
What you need is a labelled dataset (X, Y). X is a NxM matrix where N is the number of samples and M is 2 for list_length and average_time as features, X[i, 0] is the list_length of the ith training sample. Y is a N vector and N[i] is the amount of desired delay you need the system to apply.
Given the X and Y, you can train a classifier as you can see in the provided link using scikit-learn and then given a new sample x the model can predict the desired delay time using the regressor's predict function.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit ([[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [10, 100, 1000])
clf.predict([[0.5, 0.5]])
```

In this example copied from the provided scikit-learn link, the desired delays are 10, 100, 1000 for samples [0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2] respectively.
The fit function trains and fits a linear model for your data with which you can predict a new sample like [0.5, 0.5].

If you create an evaluation set (X, Y) as well, you'll be able to evaluate the performance of your model and choose the best regressor model.

Answer (score 0):

Like Afsin said, this is a regression problem. The one thing that I would wouldn't necessarily agree on is the type of regression. I think that you would be better served by trying something that is a poisson/negative binomial regression model as opposed to a linear regression model.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression) is the wikipedia link where they state

> In statistics, Poisson regression is a form of regression analysis used to model count data.

You can think of the seconds that a user has to wait as the counts that you are trying to model. If your data shows signs of over dispersion then you should model your data as a negative binomial regression model instead.

Here is an example of how you would do something like that in R.

Data

```
age mar doc und cits    
29  Yes 362 7   2   
32  No  210 6   4   
26  Yes 359 6   1   
25  Yes 181 3   1   
30  No  429 7   1   
28  Yes 359 6   0   
30  No  210 4   0   
40  Yes 347 4   0   
30  No  210 5   2
```

Let's say that you are trying to model the number of citations that postdocs have. The above data would be stored in a variable called *postdoc*

```
citations<-postdoc$cits
married<-postdoc$mar
age<-postdoc$age
prestige<-postdoc$doc
selectivity<-postdoc$und
```

You have to treat married as a *factor* because this is a categorical variable. Based off of reading your post, it sounds like you won't have to do this, but I thought that I'd mention it.

```
married<-factor(postdoc$mar,levels = c(0,1), labels = c("yes","no"))
```

This this could be one possible regression model:

```
citation.model<-glm(citations ~ married+age+prestige+selectivity, family = poisson)
```

Of course, there is a lot that I'm leaving out but that is the very basic idea. You'd have to do things like check to make sure that your model fits well of course.